# Trying to strip li tags from get_archives_link

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress theme and using `get_archives_link` to list all archive info.

`get_archives_link` as default displays the archive list wrapped around `<li></li>` tags as below.

```
<li><a href='http://localhost/blog/?m=201505'>May 2015</a></li>
```

But I would like then to be displayed as an href instead like the following example:

```
<a href='http://localhost/blog/?m=201505' class="list-group-item">May 2015</a>
```

Any ideas on how I can get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are `li`s and `a`s the only elements present in the string you have? If so http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php should suffice. `strip_tags($input, '<a>');`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the third parameter accepted by `get_archives_link()` to `'blank'`. For example:

```
get_archives_link( $url, $text, 'blank', '', '' );
```

Note: Technically, to get the job done, the third param can be anything you like accept `html`, `link` or `option`. I used blank just as an example.

Ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_archives_link

Comment: That nearly works.  I just now need to add a class to the href now.  How can I get around that?

Comment: To add a class attribute, you'd need to use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). The answer by kamal pal shows an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to achieve this, see example below :-

```
$anchorWithLi = "<li><a href='http://localhost/blog/?m=201505'>May 2015</a></li>";
echo preg_replace('#<li>(<a)(.*)</li>#i', '$1 class="list-group-item" $2', $anchorWithLi);
```

Output:

```
<a class="list-group-item"  href='http://localhost/blog/?m=201505'>May 2015</a>
```